# Infinite scrolling in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How to effectively implement infinite scrolling in Windows Phone 8.1 now that the 'LongListSelector' control is removed? I'll be using infinite scrolling in an app that reads news feed from a social network, if that matters.

Comment: seems like Windows Phone 8.1 api got ISupportIncrementalLoading interface. Check this: http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to consider infinite scrolling in 8.1, consider the listview instead of longlistselector. This was discussed in [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52e6ce68-4399-4186-b462-dbfed3a5aac4/longlistselector-in-windows-phone-81?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK) recently.

You might want to checkout [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9d3cadd3-dc95-4219-9f90-e1aae6ad25c8/infinite-scrolling-with-listview) for examples of loading social media api's with infinite scroll in listview.

Comment: Thanks, seems like what I needed.