# LongListSelector scroll down charge

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm implementing a system similar to Twitter messaging, and I would like to load the messages as does the Twitter application for mobile, by scrolling down. Can I do this with WP and LongListSelector?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a popular MSDN blog that details everything you need to load content dynamically when you scroll to the bottom.

[Create An Infinite Scrollable List With Longlistselector](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector/) (They even use Twitter as the example)

Another useful link on the topic:

[TwitterSearch - Windows Phone 8 LongListSelector Infinite Scrolling Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e)

---

Good luck

Comment: I found this looking for another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290785/infinite-scrolling-in-windows-phone-8-1). It seems that no longer works, but thanks . :)